# Reference request: What is the definition of a quasi-finite morphism of algebraic stacks?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there a generally accepted definition of quasifinite morphisms of Artin stacks?

It's not in the stacks project. I also checked LMB and Olsson's books but couldn't find a definition, though it's possible I didn't look hard enough.

I know if the morphism is representable then there's the obvious definition in terms of pullbacks being quasi-finite, but what about the general case?

References would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

A definition is given in the Stacks project (it comes from a paper by David Rydh), see [Tag 0G2L](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0G2L).

Answer (score 4):

See

Angelo Vistoli

Intersection theory on algebraic stacks and on their moduli spaces

Inventiones mathematicae (1989)

Volume: 97, Issue: 3, page 613-670

[EUDML  |  Intersection theory on algebraic stacks and on their moduli spaces.](https://eudml.org/doc/143716)

More precisely, Definition (1.8) : the morphism is of finite type and the geometric fibers are finite, in the sense that they admit a finite atlas.

Comment: Hmm, strangely they don't require that a finite morphism of stacks be representable, which makes me slightly less confident that their definition of quasifinite is standard. Argh.

Comment: Also they only give the definition of a "finite type quasifinite morphism of Deligne-Mumford stacks".

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'they'. Quasi-finiteness includes of finite type already for schemes see [Section 29.20 (01TC): Quasi-finite morphisms—The Stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01TC) .

Comment: @Niels the OP is asking about Artin stacks.